# What does it mean that we refer to Rav Shimon Bar Yochai as "Elokai"?

Tags: rabbi-shimon-bar-yochai

The popular song that's sung on Lag B'Omer goes "L'kavod Ha'Tanna *Elokai*." What does it mean that we refer to Rashbi as *elokai*? Does he possess divinity?

Comment: If it does, then the song is avoda zara

Comment: Chas Veshalom!!! The word is Elohi

Comment: צדיקים דומים לבוראם